# How to make a GET REST API request to Google Custom Search API in C#

Tags: c#, json, google-search

I have created a Google Custom Search which I can successfully call using the JSON/Atom Custom Search API and then load the results from it into a javascript function when I have a script tag within an aspx page:

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={my key}&amp;cx={my CX code};q=Shell&amp;callback=hndlr"></script>
```

However, I am trying to make this GET request within C# and I can't seem to get it to work. I haven't made GET requests before in C# so I'm sure I'm making a basic error somewhere. The code I am trying is below:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwb;

String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={my key}&amp;cx={my cx code}&amp;q=Shell";

    hwb = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)hwb.GetResponse();
```

It returns the following error when the GetResponse() call is made on the final line:

> "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Any assistance in pointing out where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated - even if it's just to confirm that this particular API can't be used in this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have on the site is exactly what you're trying, replace the `&amp;` sequences in the URL with just `&`

Comment: Yes, this was it! I just needed another pair of eyes to see my mistake. Thank Matt!